# Send notification from a PHP backend to an Android device

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to send a notification from PHP to an Android device I own. I read that Google's FCM can be used, but there's no documentation or examples on the PHP part. I tried using

```
$fcm = new Google_Service_FirebaseCloudMessaging($client);
$data = array(
    'message' => array(
        'notification' => array(
            'title' => 'FCM Message',
            'body' => 'This is an FCM Message',
        )
    )
);
$response = $fcm->send($data);
```

But it didn't work. Apparently *Google_Service_FirebaseCloudMessaging::send()* doesn't exist. I'm using google/apiclient 2.0 via composer. I'm also not sure how the Firebase project, credentials, etc need to be properly set up. To clarify, I'm not using any Android app as a notification receiver. I simply want my phone to show a notification in the simplest way possible. Maybe even using a third-party app that I need to install on the phone which offers a simple server-to-server API that I can use if Google's own can't be used.